# Javascript Event Onclick

Tags: javascript, parameters, onclick

Q1) i have written the javascript code below in which i put the onClick event and in the last parameter of the addEventListener i put the 'true' for capturing but still in console you can see bubbling is true, secondly the target at onClick remains same on both true, false parameter i.e (img object), you can check at your own pc kindly help me out of this confusion.

```js
document.querySelector('.grid').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.target.id + " " + this.className);
},true)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JavaScript Events</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif|Merriweather' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="art">
  <h2>Art Eliminator</h2>
  <p>Pick your favorite piece of art through the process of elimination. Click on the pieces you like the least until you are left with a single one. Click on the last image to get some info</p>
    <ul class="grid">
      <li id="li-1"><img src="images/Hassum_Harrod_03_tn.jpg" id="img1" alt="Hassum Harod's Summer Trees"></li>
      <li id="li-2"><img src="images/LaVonne_LaRue_02_tn.jpg" id="img2" alt="LaVonne LaRue's Mighty Duck"></li>
      <li id="li-3"><img src="images/Lorenzo_Garcia_01_tn.jpg" id="img3" alt="Lorenzo Garcia's The Dancer"></li>
      <li id="li-4"><img src="images/Jennifer_Jerome_01_tn.jpg" id="img4" alt="Jennifer Jerome's A day of Rest'"></li>
      <li id="li-5"><img src="images/Constance_Smith_03_tn.jpg" id="img5" alt="Constance Smith's Letterforms"></li>
      <li id="li-6"><img src="images/LaVonne_LaRue_04_tn.jpg" id="img6" alt="LaVonne LaRue's Flow"></li>
      <li id="li-7"><img src="images/Lorenzo_Garcia_03_tn.jpg" id="img7" alt="Lorenzo Garcia's Mother"></li>
      <li id="li-8"><img src="images/Jennifer_Jerome_02_tn.jpg" id="img8" alt="Jennifer Jerome's Farm Life"></li>
      <li id="li-9"><img src="images/Hillary_Goldwynn_03_tn.jpg" id="img9" alt="Hillary Goldwynn's Blue Sky"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Q2) In my other code when i put onclick event at one element (div) but it works on all element (div) why and how ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JavaScript Events</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="grid">
    <li><img src="images/ylw.gif" alt="yellow"></li>
    <li><img src="images/org.gif" alt="orange"></li>
    <li><img src="images/ppl.gif" alt="purple"></li>
    <li><img src="images/blu.gif" alt="blue"></li>
    <li><img src="images/pnk.gif" alt="pink" id="pink"></li>
    <li><img src="images/grn.gif" alt="green"></li>
    <li><img src="images/ygr.gif" alt="ygreen"></li>
    <li><img src="images/gry.gif" alt="gray"></li>
    <li><img src="images/red.gif" alt="red"></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="d1">1  <!-- the topmost -->
    <div class="d2">2
        <div class="d3">3 <!-- the innermost -->
        </div> 
    </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i =0; i<divs.length; i++){
    divs[0].onclick = function(event){
        event = event || window.event;
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'
        // e.stopPropagation();
        // if(event.stopPropagation){
        //     event.stopPropagation();
        // }
        // else if(event.cancelBubble()){
        //     event.cancelBubble;
        // }
        alert("Target " + target.className + ",this " + this.className);
    }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: in first question when i put the last parameter true or false in both situation  target remains same that is img object why ?

in second question there is many div elements but i put onclick event at one div but it works at all divs you can click at all divs and then it will generate results in alert

Answer (score 0):

I think u did a small mistake here..
use "event.stopPropagation();" instead of "e.stopPropagation();"

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JavaScript Events</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="grid">
    <li><img src="images/ylw.gif" alt="yellow"></li>
    <li><img src="images/org.gif" alt="orange"></li>
    <li><img src="images/ppl.gif" alt="purple"></li>
    <li><img src="images/blu.gif" alt="blue"></li>
    <li><img src="images/pnk.gif" alt="pink" id="pink"></li>
    <li><img src="images/grn.gif" alt="green"></li>
    <li><img src="images/ygr.gif" alt="ygreen"></li>
    <li><img src="images/gry.gif" alt="gray"></li>
    <li><img src="images/red.gif" alt="red"></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="d1">1  <!-- the topmost -->
    <div class="d2">2
        <div class="d3">3 <!-- the innermost -->
        </div> 
    </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i =0; i<divs.length; i++){
  divs[i].style.backgroundColor='white'; 
    divs[i].onclick = function(event){
        event = event || window.event;
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'; 
    
         event.stopPropagation();
         if(event.stopPropagation){
             event.stopPropagation();
         }
         else if(event.cancelBubble()){
             event.cancelBubble;
         }
        alert("Target " + target.className + ",this " + this.className);
    }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```